# Differentiability on the boundary of $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Is it possible to have a function being differentiable on $(a,b)$ and continuous at $a$, but not differentiable at $a$?

Btw, do we actually call a function which is one-side differentiable at the boundary simply differentiable?

Answer (score 10):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, $x\in[0,1]$, the one-sided derivative at $x=0$ does not exist.

Comment: What if it is Lipschitz continuous at $a$?

Comment: Isn't that the below example provided by @G Tony Jacobs is locally Lipschitz at $x=0$?

Comment: We only look at [0,1]. Therefore, i was thinking the definition of one-side differentiable.

Comment: Try $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$, for $x>0$, $f(0)=0$. So $|f(x)|\leq|x|$.

Answer (score 2):

An example: $f(x)=|x|$ is differentiable on $(0,b)$ for any positive $b$, but not at $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If a function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrowtail \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at the point $a \in \text{Int}(\text{dom}(f))$, then it must be continuous at $a$; but its reversal is not true.